# Giving a O365 user access in two tenants?

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps

I have two Office 365 subscriptions.

I want to give a user access to both tenants to do things like work with resources in both domains.

I would of course need to have 2 licenses for the user (one in each domain) but how can I have it so they have only one email inbox and address so they don't have to log in to two different 0365 accounts to do work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is now way to do this in the manner in which you would want.

The way I see it operating is both tenants are configured to allow external sharing with authenticated users. When user A from tenant A wants to share with user B from tenant B, user A sends an external sharing invitation to user B's email address. User B logs in with the credentials of tenant B at the log in screen instead of signing in with a Microsoft account and they get into the site.

The other option, which probably wouldn't be practical, is to consolidate subscriptions so everyone is under the same tenant and migrate mailboxes and SharePoint content into that tenant.